Apt installed python module not found by pipx installed application
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.
I'm attempting to install Electrum as a Python application, which requires the Python3 modules pyqt5 and cryptography.
I checked these modules were available:
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 python3-cryptography

These both seem to install successfully.
I then install the Electrum tarball with pipx: pipx install Electrum-4.5.8.tar.gz
Upon attempting to run electrum, I receive an error that at least one of {pycryptodomex, cryptography} needs to be installed.
Why hasn't pipx found the installed cryptography module?

pipx applications that are dependent on other modules installed in the system, need to have those modules preinstalled into the pipx virtual environment:
pipx install --preinstall pyqt5 --preinstall cryptography Electrum-4.5.8.tar.gz

